# ORA-02085: database link DBLINK_NAME connects to ORACLE

Tags: oracle, dblink

I m having a database by name 'HBHAWANI' on my domain server name 'HBHAWANI' (version Oracle 8i). Whenever I try to create a dblink here it gives the error :

```
Link  : "DBLINK_DOMAINSERVERTOUPASS_PP"  
Error : ORA-02085: database link DBLINK_DOMAINSERVERTOUPASS_PP connects to ORACLE
```

Script for DBLink is:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK DBLINK_DOMAINSERVERTOUPASS_PP  
CONNECT TO UPASS.HBHAWANI  
IDENTIFIED BY <PWD>  
USING 'UPASS.HBHAWANI';
```

I have tried so much but occurring same error. Kindly provide a suggestion on this.

Answer (score 18):

You probably have `global_names` set to `true`, and you aren't connecting quite how you think. The `connect to` is the user account on the remote database you want to reach, corresponding to the password you give in the `identified by` clause. The `using` looks like a `tnsnames.ora` entry, but one which has `connect_data` pointing to a SID of `ORACLE`; it may be helpful to add that entry to your question. It looks like you're currently giving the alias name in both the `using` and `connect to` clauses, which probably isn't correct.

With `global_names` on, the database link name has to match the remote database name - it's actual name, not the alias you've given to it. This means your database link *name* will have to be `ORACLE`, which might be a little confusing.

You could also turn off the `global_names` setting at the database level, but that may not be allowed or desirable. If this is a rarely-used link you could also add `alter session set global_names=false` before any queries that use the link. It may be less confusing in the long term to have your names consistent though.